# jquery draggable and resizeable not working nice together

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, drag

I have several DIV's that I want to make draggable and also make resizeable.  Here is my code in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QQzEoyTM5dubRuwTfZd5

There are a couple of issues that I'm having.  the first issue being that the not all the divs are resizable, just the first one.

This second being that the content of the div that is resizeable is being hidden behind the resize areas.  I'm not sure why it's doing either of these things but any help would be much appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

use Classes instead of ID's and it should work

`$(function() {
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable();
  });`

```
<div class='resizable ui-widget-content' data-need='1'>this is div 1</div>
```